# How can I rewrite a URL in Wordpress with a query variable that uses both letters and numbers?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-parameters

I want to write a custom redirect in Wordpress with a page and URL parameter. Basically, I want `/property/ABC123` to go to `index.php?pagename=property&my_id=ABC123`. This is what I have, but I think my regex is off.

```
public function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%my_id%', '([^&]+)');
}

public function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^property/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=property&my_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', [$this, 'custom_rewrite_tag'], 10, 0);
add_action('init', [$this, 'custom_rewrite_rule'], 10, 0);
```

I've refreshed my permalinks but this does not work. I also tried removing the underscore (`myid`), but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are you getting a 404? An error? Something else?

Comment: @maiorano84 The parameter isn't being picked up. `error_log($_GET['my_id'])` logs `false`. Appending the parameter without the rewrite works though (`http://example.com/property?my_id=ABC123`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [add_rewrite_tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) documentation:

> ## Retrieving the Value of a Rewritten URL
>
> With a rewrite tag defined, you can now retrieve the value of your rewritten querystring variables using WordPress's $wp_query variable. To get the value of the above tag out of a rewrite, you could use the following in your page template:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['film_title']
```

> **Note that using $_GET on a rewritten URL will not work, even if the rewrite includes the querystring variables. You must use $wp_query.**

With that in mind, you should be able to access your variable in your template like so:

```
...
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['my_id']);
...
```

If you're still having trouble, try modifying your regex to be a bit more specific. In this case, we're accepting alphanumeric characters *only*:

```
public function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%my_id%', '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)');
}

public function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^property/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=property&my_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', [$this, 'custom_rewrite_tag'], 10, 0);
add_action('init', [$this, 'custom_rewrite_rule'], 10, 0);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. It was always working. I was just testing it improperly. I totally forgot you can't use `$_GET` with query variables. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Happens to the best of us, brotato. It's an easy mistake to make.